# PostgreSQL + why archive_command line is marked after baarman restore

Tags: linux, postgresql, backup, restore, barman

I use the barman tool as backup & restore for PostgreSQL

after I restored successfully the data folder under /var/lib/pgsql by the barman

we seen that line with archive_command  was remarked by the #BARMAN# and the line - **archive_command = false** added also

as the following

```
vi /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf

#BARMAN# archive_command = 'rsync -a %p barman@107.14.23.6:/var/lib/barman/main-db-server/incoming/%f'
archive_command = false
```

this mean from this point we cant backup the data folder from the backup server
because line is marked

why barman remark the line after restore process?

can we avoid this? ( because this stop the backup process each night )

- IP - **107.14.23.6** is the backup server

example when we want to backup from barman we get this:

```
/usr/bin/barman backup main-db-server
Starting backup using rsync-exclusive method for server main-db-server in 
/var/lib/barman/main-db-server/base/20170913T135448
Backup start at xlog location: 0/1B000020 (00000003000000000000001B, 
00000020)
Copying files.
Copy done.
Asking PostgreSQL server to finalize the backup.
```

at this point the backup is stuck on -  Asking PostgreSQL server to finalize the backup

Comment: restarting master server once solved my problem